# Silly confusion about gauge invariance in supersymmetric Lagrangians - in particular, in the ${\cal N}=1$ superfield formulation of ${\cal N}=4$ SYM

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

Hoping to resolve a simple confusion I have about supersymmetric gauge theory, one which I ran into while trying to understand the ${\cal N}=1$ superfield formulation of ${\cal N}=4$ supersymmetric yang mills.

In various sources
(e.g. this review: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9908171 see eq'n 2.9, or Erdmenger's book Gauge Gravity Duality, see eq'n 3.215), there are terms in the lagrangian of the form
$$ \mathcal{L}={\rm tr} \int d^4\theta ~\Phi^\dagger e^V \Phi e^{-V}  $$
modulo different sign conventions in the textbook vs the review - this is from the book. Here $\Phi$ is a chiral superfield, and $V$ is a real superfield. Now as I understand it, the fields transform as follows under gauge transformations: $$
\Phi\to e^{i\Lambda}\Phi $$
$$
e^V \to e^{i\Lambda^\dagger} e^V e^{-i\Lambda}
$$
Clearly, the term $$\mathcal{L}=\int d^4\theta \Phi^\dagger e^V \Phi $$
is invariant under such a transformation. But if I look at the lagrangian I wrote at the top of this question, it transforms as follows, as far as I can tell:
$$
\int d^4\theta \Phi^\dagger e^V \Phi e^{-V} \to \int d^4\theta \Phi^\dagger e^V \Phi e^{-i\Lambda^\dagger} e^{-V} e^{i\Lambda}
$$
Doesn't seem very gauge invariant. What am I missing here?

Comment: A possible answer is to consider decomposing under the basis.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the ${\cal N}=1$ chiral field $\Phi\to e^{i\Lambda}\Phi e^{-i\Lambda}$ and the ${\cal N}=1$ vector field $V\to e^{i\Lambda}V e^{-i\Lambda}$ are assumed to transform in the [adjoint representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation)  of a unitary gauge group (so that $\Lambda=\Lambda^{\dagger}$ is Hermitian).

Also notice that the Lagrangian term has a gauge group trace in front unlike the standard construction.